# secActivity only sometimes call StartActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-listview

I have some issues while calling **startActivityForResult from onClickListener**.

In the first activity i have 2 ways of starting `startActivityForResult`

1. `ListView` with `OnItemClick()` -when i'm calling `startActivityForResult` from the `ListView OnItemClick()` it works just fine
2. `Button` with `OnClickListener()`-but when i'm calling startActivityForResult from the `Button OnClickListener()` the second activity wont start `OnActivityResult` from some reasone.
   here is my code:

*Update:
thank you for your time, what you offerd is one of the changes I allready tried, however its stays the same my new code:

first call with StartActivityForResult()  ( Works Fine! - inside OnCreate() ):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(NoteNames.this, EditNote.class);
            intent.putExtra("subject", noteList.get(position).getSubjectText());
            intent.putExtra("body", noteList.get(position).getBodyText());
            startActivityForResult(intent, position);
        }


    });
```

Second call: wont start OnActivityResult():

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v.getId() == addButton.getId()){
        Intent intent = new Intent(NoteNames.this, EditNote.class);
        intent.putExtra("subject", "");
        intent.putExtra("body", "");
        startActivityForResult(intent, idOfNew);
    }

}
```

this is the SecondActivity:

```
private EditText subjectEditText, bodyEditText;
private Button approve, decline;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_note);

    subjectEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note_head);
    bodyEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note_text);
    approve = (Button) findViewById(R.id.approve_button);
    decline = (Button) findViewById(R.id.decline_button);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String subject = intent.getExtras().getString("subject");
    String body = intent.getExtras().getString("body");

    subjectEditText.setText(subject);
    bodyEditText.setText(body);

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    approve.setOnClickListener(handler);
    decline.setOnClickListener(handler);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

class Handler implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {



         if (v.getId()==approve.getId()){
             Intent intent = getIntent();
             intent.putExtra("subject", String.valueOf(subjectEditText.getText()));
             intent.putExtra("body", String.valueOf(bodyEditText.getText()));
             setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
             finish();
         }

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Before you edited your question, in your code was written `final int idOfNew=-5` . Well, if the `requestCode<0` then the `onActivityResult` is **not** triggered. Use a request code `>0` (maybe the id of the button), this should solve your problem. Everything else in your code is just fine.

Comment: mihail thank you for your time, i'm still havent figure out how to post code in a comment so i updated my original question.

Comment: i'll try to reproduce the problem.